# Filter CloudWatch logs with Lambda Python function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have this code:

```
with open('/home/adiel/log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        if line[6] in {'443', '65535'} and line[4] in {'172.18.0.5'} :
            print(line[3:7])
        elif line[6] in {'443', '65535'} and line[4] in {'172.18.0.37'}:
            print(line[3:7])
```

That returns me the right result.
I want to change its input from /home/adiel/log to a CloudWatch Log Group named mgr. So, how can I accoplish this task?
Thanks!